Induced voltage circuit
I wonder why LED1 is turned on in the Joule Thief circuit and wirelessly connected LED2 is not. I thought when the transistor is off, the secondary coil has a large amount of induced voltage, and then induced voltage occurs at the coil where LED2 is connected.


If you look at the image of the circuit below which is taken from the Wikipedia article Joule thief you will see that the transformer is would around a ferrite? core.

This is to make sure that the magnetic coupling between the two coils is strong.  In your image you seem to have done this by winding the coils very close to one another.
However the coil associated with LED2 is not wound in such a way and so the magnetic coupling is weak, ie leakage of magnetic field from the two coils is weak resulting in an induced emf/current in the third coil connected to LED2 which is insufficient to light LED2.

The LED2 didn't light up even if I placed it close enough.

What happens if you flip the coil over, reversing voltage to the LED?

@Rich It doesnt work.
